# DDE error 285 (An application refused to perform the DDE)

Tags: basic, dde

I have an error 285 when two old application try to communicate using DDE. I  have the sourcecode but can't compile because it uses DAO.

What is the best way of debug the DDE communication and sort this error?

I have machines with Windows 10, Windows 7 and Windows XP (very old machine). I value solutions that use .net (VB.net or C#) since Visual Basic IDE (Visual Basic 6) can only run on Windows 7 or early OS. I understand that DDE is a very old tech, not supported by Microsoft. See ["Please feel free to stop using DDE" blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070226-00/?p=27863) (2007)

Comment: There is a error in the statement "Visual Basic an run only on Windows 7". I have it (for maintenance of old apps) still running on Windows 10 (64bit)

Comment: Even if Visual Basic 6 runs on windows 10, it's not supported by Microsoft and don't get security updates.

Comment: I have my own commercial accounting software running just fine on Windows 10.  Maybe you have trouble installing VB6 on Windows 10?

Comment: @PedroPolonia: Ok, than rewrite your software with a more modern tool. Be careful: Maybe Microsoft will not support .NET 4.8 in a few years from now....

Comment: Have you looked into the Windows error logs?

Comment: yes, i looked in the logs. I need code to create a mock